# Populate with Data

Tags: javascript

The pie chart displays an empty chart after loading.
I referred
 https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.data

and in **html**

```
<script>
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        accessibility: {
            point: {
                valueSuffix: '%'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'counts',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [
                    {% for item in dataset %}
                            { name: {{ item.category }}, y: {{ item.issues }} },
                    {% endfor %}
                  ]
        }]
    });

    </script>
```

Kindly let me know what I should change in order to populate the chart. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at how the data structure should look like in the pie series:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.data

And here is a reproduction of your JS code: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/837mu2q5/

```
  series: [{
    name: 'counts',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
      y: 0,
      name: "High",
    }, {
      y: 4,
      name: "Medium",
    }, {
        y: 8,
      name: "Low"
    }]
  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a field of choices on your model if you haven't already done that. I'm thinking something like this since I do not know the field 'issues' is value of your 'catagory' or a field by itself.

```
HIGH = 'H'
MEDIUM = 'M'
LOW = 'L'
MY_CHOICES = (
    (HIGH, 'High_value'),
    (MEDIUM, 'Medium_value'),
    (LOW, 'Low_value'),
)
```

Then pass it to the field choices of object category. `ex: category = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=MY_CHOICES).` Do the same for issues if they are two separate fields. Your view needs some works so I recommend you use a dictionary or tuple to store the data. Then you can embed your view function in your template and also do an ajax call to instruct your back-end that you're expecting a JSON object in return. 
Ex:

```
<div id="container" data-url="{% url 'catagory_data' %}"></div>
```

and below

```
 $.ajax({
    url: $("#container").attr("data-url"),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      Highcharts.chart("container", data);
    },
  });
```

Your view can be written like  this -

Suppose you have a model Catagory

```
def catagory_data(request):
dataset = Catagory.objects \
    .values('catagory') \
    .exclude(catagory='') \
    .annotate(total=Count('catagory')) \
    .order_by('catagory')
display_name = dict()
for cata_tuple in Catagory.MY_CHOICES:
    display_name[cata_tuple[0]] = cata_tuple[1]

chart = {
    'chart': {'type': 'pie'},
    'title': {'text': 'Appscan Vulnerabilities\, 2020'},
    'series': [{
        'name': 'catagory counts',
        'data': list(map(lambda row: {'name': display_name[row['catagory']], 'y': row['issues']}, dataset))
    }]
}


return JsonResponse(chart)
```

And you can render your template in another function

```
return render(request, 'appscan.html')
```

I think you can do the same for issues or you can write it in the same view depending on your design.

Comment: You're welcome. The smile is contiguous. Out of curiosity, Sebastian answer only showed you how to display the static data so how did you iterate and parse?

Comment: Yes, That was actually a partial answer. I was looking for something like a JSON. And there was a function called JSONResponse in views.py. I was able to retrieve it back to Javascript and all I had to do is map those JSON values to name and y inside data. :)

Comment: Ah... I left it for you to decide and figure out :) It was obvious you expect a response and I knew you would ask or figure it out what kind of response you expect and you did :). Anyways, good to know...